# Enable CORS for SignalR in Azure Mobile services .Net Backend

Tags: azure, signalr, cors, azure-mobile-services

There are several questions about enabling CORS for SignalR in Azure Mobile Services for a .Net Backend.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034259/signalr-cors-on-azure-mobile-services-web-api) is the best solution I've found, but I'm having trouble with 'System.Web.Cors' version when deploy to Azure Mobile Services. The application tries to load the version 5.0.0 when I'm deploying version 5.1.0.

If I configure CORS only for WebApi it works fine with version 5.1.0.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try and use the 5.0.0 version? We do indeed have this as an issue but I haven't had a chance to look at it in detail. Hope to be able to do shortly.

Henrik

Comment: Thanks Enrik. I've tried but it doesn't work with my other dependencies. I hope you can resolve this in short...